# How to match this location Nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

So I have this kind of location: `someplacecat.com`
Where `someplace` is dynamic and differs. 
And I want to rewrite it to `someplace.ourdomain.com`

So I wrote this location block:

`location ~ (.*)cat(.*) {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$1.ourdomain$2$request_uri;
}`

But I can't get it to match, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it using an if block, but if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with the location block, please let me know.

```
if ($host ~* (.*)cat\.(.*)) {
    set $subdomain $1;
    set $tld $2;
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$subdomain.ourdomain.$tld$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Nice ... The Nginx `if` is specifically for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

the problem with your location block

```
location ~ (.*)cat(.*) { rewrite ^ $scheme://$1.ourdomain$2$request_uri; }
```

is that the rewrite directive resets the backreferences to the ones for it's first argument, so you need to save those before the rewrite like so:

```
location ~ (.*)cat(.*) { 
  set $subdomain $1; 
  set $tld $2;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$subdomain.ourdomain.$tld$request_uri; 
}
```

which is pretty much what you did with the if-block in your anwser below (otherwise it would have the same problem :)

Comment: It didn't work though. Seems like it never enters the location block.

Comment: there's a difference in the regexp between my location block above and the regexp in your if-block that solved it below, that's probably the problem? (I matched with case-sensitive with ~ instead of case-insensitive with ~*, and I don't have the extra \. after the cat)

Comment: Tried that but I'm afraid it's still not working, the \. is just added to not catch the period before the tld in the last group, for clarity.

Comment: just figured it out: location matches on $request_uri which does not include the $host while your if-block below is matching against $host. Hence the location block not getting entered. (me smacks head, should've noticed that earlier :D)